# How to call java Program and to use argv

Tags: java, argv

I'd like to replace Int[] mydata and to use the array argv and to call my class Graph with javafx from another class with javax, 
from there I declare my array of strings and call my java program.
- Now I need to call my class from another Program with string like mydata.
and
- To use the array argv and to build my new array.

Is that possible? and how?
Thank you for your Help.

```
public class Graph extends Application {

public void start(Stage stage) {

    int[] mydata = {
            12, 9, 0, 1, 38, 19, 21, 72, 33, 83, 14, 10, 65, 46, 10, 17, 27, 38, 65, 98, 8, 58, 38, 79, 37, 69, 26, 15};
    Pane root = new Pane();
    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();


    ScatterChart scatterChart=new ScatterChart(xAxis,yAxis);
    scatterChart.setTitle("Chart");
    XYChart.Series data=new XYChart.Series();
    data.setName("Data");
    for (int i=0; i< mydata.length; i++) {
        data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i,mydata[i]));
        }

    scatterChart.getData().addAll(data);
    root.getChildren().add(scatterChart);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 600);

    //scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
    //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
    scatterChart.setPrefSize(1000, 600);
    stage.setTitle("Graph");
    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();

    File file = new File("c:\\Images\\Image.png");

    WritableImage snapshot = scene.snapshot(null);
    BufferedImage bimg = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null); 
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bimg, "png", file);
    } catch (Exception s) {
        s.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    launch(argv);
}

}
```

Comment: argv is String[] and you want to move it to an int[] ? Integer.parseInt() maybe?

Comment: Thank you, i've used Integer.parsInt() but I became mistakes

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
     
     int[] list = new int [argv.length];
     for(int i = 0; i < argv.length; i++) {
      list[i] = Integer.parseInt(argv[0]);
     }
        //System.out.println(liste[i]);
        launch(list);

and I Think that my new list is unknown in the method start(Stage stage)

Comment: plus beware command line limitation from your OS, if you want to pass a lot of data you may overflow max command line length. You'd better use a temp file if you have > 100 values

Comment: OK, 
I think, I need to use a temp file because sometimes I have more than 100 values.

Comment: @Lolitta your list injection into the method `start` seems to be not working. Can you share your code of method `launch`

Comment: Launch is a javafx application, I think, I can't use argv or temp file to read my values from another java program.  ... I have no idea :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have access to the `arguments` given to your `main` method in your `start` method in order to convert it into integers, you can call the method `getParameters().getUnnamed()`. More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--).

Then to convert your `List` of `String` into a `List` of `Integer`, you can do something like this:

With Java 8:

```
List<Integer> mydata = arguments.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With Java 7:

```
List<Integer> mydata = new ArrayList<>(arguments.size());
for (String argument : arguments) {
    mydata.add(Integer.parseInt(argument));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nicolas, with the method getParameters().getUnnamed() I have access to the `arguments` but I become still mistakes from List<Integer> mydata = arguments.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: What are the arguments that you provide to your application?

Comment: Do we agree that the code above assumes that arguments is the value of getParameters().getUnnamed(), right?

Comment: I've set some values as Arguments in the debug configurations and I see my values as Variables under Parameters  --> unnamedParams [ 12, 9, 0, 1, 38, 19, 21, 72, 33, 83, 14, 10, 65, 46, 10, 17, 27, 38, 65, 98, 8, 58, 38, 79, 37, 69, 26, 15 ]  and now I need to convert List of String into a List of Integer.

Comment: so if you call getParameters().getUnnamed().stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList()) as mentioned above, it fails?

Comment: Multiple markers at this line: the type List is not generic, Collectors cannot be resolved, syntax errror on tocken, Integer cannot be resolved,

Comment: which version of the JDK do you use?

Comment: Collectors is aactually the class java.util.stream.Collectors, it is new in java 8 like the package java.util.stream

Comment: Thank you Nicolas, I become the mistake arguments cannot be resolved as variable :( . I maked some changes like create local variable "arguments" but I become other mistakes.

Comment: java code:         

 List<Integer> mydata = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Parameters parameters = getParameters();
        List<String> unnamedParameters = parameters.getUnnamed();

        for(String unnamed : unnamedParameters) {
            System.out.println(unnamed);
            mydata.add(Integer.parseInt(unnamed));
        }

Comment: NOW I'd like to call my class "GRAPH" with javafx from another class "BUTTONS" , from there I declare my array of strings  [ 12, 9, 0, 1, 38, 19, 21, 72, 33, 83, 14, 10, 65, 46, 10, 17, 27, 38, 65, 98, 8, 58, 38, 79, 37, 69, 26, 15 ]. I used an ArrayList<String> argument = new ArrayList<String>();  ChartPenData.main(argument);  error: The method main(String[]) in the type ChartPenData is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>)

Comment: Indeed it is an array of String that is expected by the main method not a list of String

Comment: ok,  I need to use String [] arguments = new String [Data.length];

Comment: It works fine now, Thank you very match Nicolas :) I have learned so much from you, Thank you :)